# What is the best way to convert a printed list in Python back into an actual list

Tags: python, string, list

So given the a a textual representation of a list

```
['cellular organisms', 'Bacteria', 'Bacteroidetes/Chlorobi group', 'Bacteroidetes',   'Bacteroidia', 'Bacteroidales', 'Bacteroidaceae', 'Bacteroides', 'Bacteroides vulgatus']
```

What is the easiest way to convert this text back into an actual list within a python script?
Is split really the best way? Thanks!

Comment: `eval`? (as long as the input is safe)

Comment: Is there a good reason for having this text in this format to begin with? Have you considered using JSON?

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> import ast
>>> a = "['cellular organisms', 'Bacteria', 'Bacteroidetes/Chlorobi group', 'Bacteroidetes',   'Bacteroidiroidales', 'Bacteroidaceae', 'Bacteroides', 'Bacteroides vulgatus']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
['cellular organisms', 'Bacteria', 'Bacteroidetes/Chlorobi group', 'Bacteroidetes', 'Bacteroidia', 'Bacteroidales', 'Bacteroidaceae', 'Bacteroides', 'Bacteroides vulgatus']
```

From the [ast module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#module-ast):

> ast.**literal_eval**(*node_or_string*)
>
> > Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or *Latin-1* encoded string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and **None**.
> >
> > This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

Comment: That was fast. Thanks!

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: The input string as provided isn't JSON compatible.

Comment: What about `JSON.dumps(a.replace('\'', '"'))` ?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: The function in use is provided by the standard library for this use case. Editing input strings to coerce them to JSON format is likely to be error-prone.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: Python literal syntax is similar to JSON but not identical. So you can try to patch the former up to look like the latter (and your replacement works for this example), but why bother? One reason I can think, is if you want to rule out something appearing in the literal string that is not part of JSON, for example a tuple or set. But if that's what you want to do you should probably just mandate JSON input in the first place, or parse the string as a Python literal and check the result for illegal types.

Comment: Note also that your replacement code fails for another example, `a = '\'\\\'\''`. Then `ast.literal_eval(a)` is a single-quote, but `json.loads(a.replace('\'', '"'))` is a double-quote. Another example that doesn't work, `a = repr('"')`.